# graph trend filtering results from different maxflow algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow

We have followed the official code of the Graph trend filtering (GTF) https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7690, and modified the code with Ford Fulkerson Algorithm (FFA) instead of parametric maxflow. The parametric maxflow and the FFA have the same residual capacities.

We also implemented the push-relabel algorithm, but the residual capacities are different from parametric maxflow or FFA. Can anyone with experience in GTF assure that the outputs of GTF are the same even though the residual capacities are different?